# Split string depending on the existence of a leading character

Tags: php, string, explode

In PHP, I need to split a string by ":" characters without a leading "*".

This is what using explode() does:

```
$string = "1*:2:3*:4";
explode(":", $string);
output: array("1*", "2", "3*", "4")
```

However the output I need is:

```
output: array("1*:2", "3*:4")
```

How would I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '1*:2:3*:4';
$res = preg_split('~(?<!\*):~',$str);
print_r($res);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1*:2
    [1] => 3*:4
)
```

The pattern basically says:

> split by [a colon that is not lead by an asterisk]

Comment: More elegant than mine, apparently I somehow managed to miss the existence of `preg_split()` :P

Comment: @Maccath thanks. I was thinking to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) as well but then I remembered there's this function that I rarely need/use :) Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `preg_match_all()` rather than `explode()`, as you are attempting a more complex split than `explode()` itself can handle. `preg_match_all()` will allow you to gather all of the parts of a string that match a specific pattern, expressed using a regular expression. The pattern you are looking for is something along the lines of:

> anything except : followed by *: followed by anything but :

So, try this instead:

```
preg_match_all('/[^:]+\*:[^:]+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which will output something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1*:2
            [1] => 3*:4
        )

)
```

Which you should be able to use in much the same way that you would use the results of `explode()` even if there is the added dimension in the array (it divides the matches into 'groups', and all your results match against the whole expression or the first (0th) group).